# Browser autocomplete do not remember all items

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I've enabled browser autocomplete in my form but I don't understand why it doesn't remember all values that I typed to form before pressed a submit button.

For example I've typed about 20 numbers to my input and after each of them i've been pressed submit but it remember only 3 entered numbers. Why?

[image]

Comment: It shows you three most propable values. It's the most efficient way. If you'd like to show more you would have to either cover your page or add scrollbar and each of those ways are ugly. If you write in an input more specific value it will show you what you are looking for. It's also because user could be scared seeing so many results.

Comment: where did you read that? For example, I've used "12345678" about 5 times but still do not see it in autocomplete, and used "1234567833" just once and it's in autocomplete.

Comment: The "on" keyword indicates that the user agent is allowed to provide the user with autocompletion values, but does not provide any further information about what kind of data the user might be expected to enter. User agents would have to use heuristics to decide what autocompletion values to suggest. ([Autocomplete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofilling-form-controls:-the-autocomplete-attribute))